# I'm working with a tutorial and I got the error: The view main.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a very simple Django Website but I keep getting the same problem. my views.py file is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item

def index(response, id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(response, "main/base.html", {})

def home(response):
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {})
```

I've checked all necessary indentation and syntax. I'm actually following an online tutorial but I think there's the problem is with my code

Comment: oh. im very sorry that the code wasnt well posted. I probably made a mistake

Comment: Code looks good. Maybe you forgot to save the files or load them again?

Comment: @Fortune Olawale you are passing an empty dictionary. Is it supposed to be like this?